# Getting the max of each subtype in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following table:

**my_table**

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 |
| a1 | b1 |
| a1 | b2 |
| a2 | b1 |
| a2 | b2 |
| a2 | b2 |
| a2 | b2 |

I would like a query that will return me for each type of b find the a with the max count of b type and its count.
For example in the above table I would like the result will be:

| b | a_with_max_b | MAX(count_of_b) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | a1 | 2 |
| b2 | a2 | 3 |

So far I arrive to this query:

```
SELECT b , MAX(count_of_b)
FROM 
    (SELECT a, b, COUNT(b) count_of_b
     FROM my_table 
     GROUP BY  a, b) 
GROUP BY b;
```

This will return me the correct result but without the a.

| b | MAX(count_of_b) |
| --- | --- |
| b1 | 2 |
| b2 | 3 |

But if I am adding the a :

```
SELECT b, a a_with_max_b , MAX(count_of_b) 
FROM 
    (SELECT a, b, COUNT(b) count_of_b
     FROM my_table 
     GROUP BY  a, b) 
GROUP BY b;
```

I will receive just a random a and not the correct one. For example:

| b | a_with_max_b | MAX(count_of_b) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | a1 | 2 |
| b2 | a1 | 3 |

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
Elad

Comment: *What am I missing?* You miss/disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode. Enabling it will show that your query is incorrect.

Comment: What is precise MySQl version?

Comment: @Akina Thanks I was not aware to this flag , but yes I assumed the result will be wrong since the a is not on the group by clause, I was just lookin for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) counts
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY a, b
```

gives raw counts data, and reuse it as subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) counts
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY a, b
) m
WHERE ( b, counts ) IN (
  SELECT b, MAX(counts)
  FROM (
    SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) counts
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY a, b
  ) n
  GROUP BY b
)
```

Comment: This is correct. As you are using the base query twice, though, I'd put it in a `WITH` clause, so as to have the query more readable and thus enhance mantainability.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner it works for older versions with standard SQL. If it's v8.0, CTE & window functions create simpler query

Comment: Ah, yes, I keep forgetting that some people still use old MySQL versions :-)

Answer (score 0):

This involves two steps:

1. counting the rows per a and b
2. finding the maximum count per b

and then showing only the a and b pairs with a maximum count per b of course.

```
select b, a as a_with_max_b, max_count_of_b
from
(
  select
    a, b,
    count(*) as cnt,
    max(count(*)) over (partition by b) as max_count_of_b
  from my_table
  group by a, b
)
where cnt = max_count_of_b
order by b, a;
```